# show/hide malfunction - could someone point out my error?

Tags: javascript, function, xhtml

I'm working on a simple show/hide function for div elements and my issue is that after clicking a button that then reveals two links, subsequently clicking on either of the two revealed links causes them to become hidden.

```
My script:

<script type="text/javascript">

  function showHide(divId)
        {
            if(document.getElementById(divId).style.display === 'none')
            {
                document.getElementById(divId).style.display='inline';
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
</script>

The affected code:

<div id="section">

    <button type="button" onclick="showHide('sub1');">
        <h2>Select</h2>
    </button>

    <div class="menu"><!-- enclosing all the menus in the menu class-->

        <!--display:none makes the object disappear and taken out of the flow of the
        document -->
        <ul style="display:none" id="sub1" class="menu">

            <!--first submenu-->
            <li><a href="" onclick="showHide('ePage');">ePage</a></li>
            <li><a href="" onclick="showHide('wVillage');">wVillage</a></li>                        

        </ul>
        <div style="display:none" id="ePage">

            <img src="ePage.jpg" alt="Photo: ePage" />

        </div>
        <div style="display:none" id="wVillage">

            <img src="wVillage.jpg" alt="Photo: wVillage" />

        </div>

    </div>
```

The intent is to press the 'Select' button which will then reveal the two links which will be clicked to reveal two images - if the links are clicked again, the images should become hidden. Could someone tell me why the links are hiding themselves?

Edit: For future reference, I edited the empty href attributes of the a elements to "#" and the script to:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

            function showHide(divId)
            {
                node=document.getElementById(divId);

                if(node.style.display==="none")
                {
                    node.style.display="inline";
                }
                else
                {
                    node.style.display="none";
                }
            }
    </script>
```

*As suggested, this indeed saves effort by saving the div element's id to a node instead of making 3 calls.

Comment: That code seems to work fine for me. Probably your anchor (`a`) tag is redirecting on click.

Comment: Try adding a `return false;` to the `onclick` attribute of the `a` tag after the `showHide(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works properly, but after the showHide logic is executed, the default functionality of the `<a>` tag takes place, refreshing the page. To prevent it you can change the href attribute to something that won't refresh the page (example: `#`), or you can preventDefault on the click event.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/eGejurO/2/edit

PS: (Unrelated) You could save the reference to the element you are show/hiding instead of looking for it 3 times in the same function.

Comment: Thank you for all the great comments! This was my first ever post - Special thanks to Tibos for your jsbin example.